# Font Awesome & Unicode in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, icons, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I want to use FontAwsome in react-native with UNICODE's.
A part of my code:

```
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'; 

    <Icon name="&#xf015;" size={50} color="#5b5b5b" />
```

This is not working. If I write `name="cogs"` everything is OK.

I need to be shown with unicode.

I want to show icon with unicode. is there any library or any way to show icon with unicode I want to learn it.

Do you have any idea?

Solution :

`<Text style={{fontFamily:'fontAwesome',fontSize:80,color:'#424242'}}>&#xf085;</Text>`

Comment: Icon's name prop only accept string name of that icon not unicode. can you elaborate the question.what you want to do? what to render with Icon Compoent

Comment: I want to show icon with unicode. is there any library or any way to show icon with unicode I want to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can render UNICODE's like this

```
<Text style={{fontFamily:'fontAwesome'}}>
  &#xf015;
</Text>
```

Comment: `<Text style={{fontFamily:'fontAwesome',fontSize:80,color:'#424242'}}>&#xf085;</Text>`
Like this is work. Thank You!